# UIImage imageNamed returning nil unexpectedly

Tags: ios, uiimage

I have a custom button subclass in my app that, when tapped, will show a custom activity indicator animation. It's implemented with a series of 32 images, using `UIImageView`'s [`animationImages`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimageview/1621068-animationimages?language=objc) property. Loading all those images involves a noticeable delay, so I cache them in a static array in the button and load them in the background at startup. They're named "buy_anim0001.png" through "buy_anim0032.png". I have this method, and I call it at the end of `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
+(void)setup
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        CFTimeInterval start = CACurrentMediaTime();
        NSMutableArray<UIImage *> *images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        int numImages = 32;
        for (int i = 1; i <= numImages; i++)
        {
            NSString *title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"buy_anim%04i.png", i];
            UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:title];
            [images addObject:img];
        }
        CFTimeInterval end = CACurrentMediaTime();
        NSLOG(@"Took %.3f seconds to load buy button images", end - start);

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            _images = images;
        });
    });
}
```

I never got a crash here in development or in external beta testing the app, but now I'm seeing crash reports from here, complaining about "[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil".

Some notes:

- The crash is all on iOS 12 (because this version of the app requires iOS 12, and 13 is still a few hours away from shipping)
- The app is in the background 75% of the time, but I've tried forcing this to happen while the app isn't in foreground and I get no crash.
- I've double-checked the image naming, but if that were the issue then this would have shown up in debug or beta.
- There are no casing issues in the file names.
- There are not @2x versions of the images, and they're in the project and not an asset catalog, so I don't think app thinning is the issue.

So...what can cause `UIImage imageNamed` to return `nil` once in a great while when the image name is correct?

**Update:** I discovered that putting the images in an asset catalog instead of the bundle makes them load *way* faster (a second or two down to less than a tenth of a second). This likely removes the need to load them in the background, so I'll at least be doing that for the next release. That might solve the issue.

Comment: I have seen reported crash reports where the only explanation for how the crash could happen is if `UIImage imageNamed` returned `nil`.  I was never able to reproduce the crash and the crash was VERY rare, even though it was in code that executed a lot.  I ended up just working around it and putting nil protections in place and then part of my interface is missing an image when this rare case happens and my app doesn't crash.  Not really an ideal fix, but it wasn't a critical image.